# Implementing ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) in a functional language

Tags: architecture, functional-programming, erlang, esb

I am hoping that an architecture question is reasonable on Stackoverflow, so I am asking this here.

I have been trying to see where a functional language would be useful outside of math-oriented problems, and it dawned on me that an ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) would be perfect for a FP language, as there isn't anything shared between requests, in my experience, as the initial message comes in and gets processed as it goes through, based on transform rules.

Would there be any reason why this would be a bad idea?

Is it in the progress of being done already?

The scalability of something like Erlang may be very useful I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say anything more insightful than "yes, you're right."  The first production uses of Clojure are exactly that.

Comment: Is there something I can look at to see this production use?

Comment: There's a little tqalk about it in the Clojure groups.  I'm supposed to be writing an article on it for CIO but that's been stalled.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com). It is not really the ESB, rather enterprise messaging system, but interesting.